# express static assets not working deep route something/something

Tags: node.js, express

In my express app the static assets will not serve on `something/something`.

```
/**
 * Express configuration.
 */
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
// app.use(compress());
// app.use(assets({
//   paths: ['public/css', 'public/js']
// }));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public/favicon.png')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: secrets.sessionSecret,
  store: new MongoStore({ url: secrets.db, autoReconnect: true })
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());
app.use(lusca({
  csrf: true,
  xframe: 'SAMEORIGIN',
  xssProtection: true
}));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  next();
});
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (/api/i.test(req.path)) req.session.returnTo = req.path;
  next();
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));
```

Then in my main layout

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

The home page works, but not the nested routes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your stylesheet href is a relative link which means it will be interpreted by the browser to be relative to the path of the current web page, so it will be interpeted differently for a nested path, than a top level web page.  You probably need to change your link to be this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

So that it is interpreted the same, no matter what the path of the webpage you put it in happens to be.

Given your `express.static()` code, then this path `"/css/main.css"` will be looked for as `__dirname + "/assets/css/main.css"`.

Comment: Was looking for this as well. Just made my day. Thank you!